# How Do I Touch Draw Square on Canvas?

Tags: html, canvas, touch, draw

Yea, I was just wondering, why can't I draw a square on the canvas with the touch? What am I doing wrong? Please, any help at all would be greatly appreciated:)

Here's code:

---

JAVASCRIPT:

```
  // "Square" Button
function square()
{   
var can = document.getElementById('canvasSignature');
var ctx = can.getContext('2d');


can.addEventListener( 'touchstart', onTouchStart, false);

function onTouchStart(e) {
 ctx.fillRect(0,0,300,300);   

}
}
```

---

HTML5:

```
  <div id="canvasDiv">
<canvas id="canvasSignature" width="580px" height="788px" style="border:2px solid #000; background: #FFF;"></canvas>
  </div>

  <div id="Square">  
<p><button onclick="square();">Square</button></p>
  </div>
```

Comment: I suggest using gee.js to handle user input. It also supports touch events: http://georgealways.github.com/gee/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works just fine in JSfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/jXv83/

I have a feeling that `square()` is never getting called so the code you have up there is never run...

Comment: Soo, how would I go about calling the **square()** function so that it will actually run?

Comment: don't have a square function, just have a self-executing function, or make it the square() function run on body or window load